# Nested "for" loops c++

Tags: c++, loops, initialization

On the way to understand working of nested for loop i wrote a program that takes a input and display a pyramid upto that input value like this:

```
1
22
333
4444
```

It's displaying just the height of pyramid but its not displaying written part in the second for loop.

Here is the code(after modification but required result not yet)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
    int num;
    cout << "Enter the number of pyramid" << endl ;
    cin >> num ;
    for (int i = 0; i < num ; i++)
    {
        int max;

        for (int j = 0 ; j <= max ; j++)
        {
            cout << j ;
        }

        cout  << endl ;
        max++ ;
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: you have not initialized max

Comment: Please take the time to correctly indent your code before asking for help with it.

Comment: @Jack That's a valid answer. Post it as a one.

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;

 int main(void)
  {
    int num ;
    cout << "Enter the number of pyramid" << endl ;
    cin >> num ;
    for (int i = 0; i < num ; i++)
    {
      int max  = i +1; //change 1

      for (int j = 0 ; j < max ; j++)
      {
        cout << max; //change 2
      }

      cout  << endl ;
      //max++ ; //change 3
    }
    system("PAUSE") ;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: then `max++` is useless, as stated by @riv

Comment: `max` goes out of scope by next iteration, so incrementing it there does nothing. Either declare `max` outside of the loop, or simply use `i + 1` instead.

Answer (score 2):

You should initialize max to 0.

```
int max = 0;
```

Additionally there are two more bugs.

```
int max ;
```

1. should be declared before the for loop for i. (Otherwise max is defined to be 0 always)
2. In the inner loop print i, not j.

Comment: That's not enough, he's incrementing max just before it goes out of scope, so another change is needed.

Comment: @riv : Thanks, two changes were needed.

Comment: Im understanding my mistakes now if im giving height of pyramid to be 5 for example it just displaying height 4 and everything is alright.

Comment: Small changes can impact big :) solved problem ,now everything is alright, God these small conditions are critical to understand,woould be helpful if anyone provide me a link which make me understand these for loop conditions.

Comment: Good. You need to read a good C++ beginner book. Don't forget to accept either of these answers.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, please try to have a proper structure in your code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(void)
{
   int num;
   cout << "Enter the number of pyramid" << endl;
   cin >> num;

   for(int i = 0; i < num; i++)
   {
      int max;

      for(int j = 0; j <= max; j++)
      {
         cout << j;
      }

      cout  << endl;
      max++;
   }

   system("PAUSE");
   return 0;
}
```

And your mistake:
Change `int max;` to `int max = 0;`
You cannot add 1 to a non existing value.

Comment: You CAN add 1 to an unitialized value, but it's undefined behavior ;-)

Answer (score 1):

As has been stated in other answers, your max counter isn't initialized. Additionally, you don't really need it, as you already have `i` doing the same task:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    {
        cout << i;
    }

    cout << endl;     
}
```

Comment: @rajraj - yeah, I copied OP's across and forgot to change it.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you actually want to print something like 0 01 012 0123, this is the code you're looking for:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= num; i++)
{
  for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
    cout << i;
  cout << endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

max is not set to an initial value.

Its declared insides 1st loop and then used in the 2nd loop.